# How to show Dynamic legend for categories using unique values of a field in ArcGIS JavaScript?

Tags: legend, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcmap, arcgis-server

I am using arc gis api for java script 3.16. We are facing issues for showing dynamically category wise legend. i have Draw categories using unique values of one field in symbology of layer property arc map 10.3.1 and than publish this .mxd file as a map service and this service use in my program and i want to show only those legend category symbol which are exist on map but my map show legend according to layer wise if layer is on legend show properly but i am showing only those symbol which value are exist on map not all.

i am using this code for showing legend.

```
    var legend = new Legend({
map : map,
layerInfos : [ { 
layer : layer,
title : "Legend"
} ]
}, "legend");
legend.startup();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I am having trouble understanding your question so I will try to reiterate it and tell me if this is correct: You would like to show one specific layer in the legend. This layer has symbology for each unique value and you would only like to only show the symbols for *values that are in the current map extent*. Is that correct?